# Dietro di me vs. dietro a me

Tags: prepositions

Are these uses of prepositions interchangeable in the above example, or do they have different emphasis/meanings/uses?

Answer (score 4):

You can use "dietro a" for verbs that indicate movement, like

- andare: go
- correre: run
- camminare: walk

> Io cammino dietro a Luigi.

You can use "dietro di" when it precedes a pronoun:

> Io corro dietro di te

Remember that "dietro a" is more literary, for example Dante used it:

"Vien dietro a me, e lascia dir le genti" (Purgatory)